# Title and a text without any space

Tags: titles, paragraphs

I have definend "title" of subsub section as following:

```
\def\podpodsekce#1{\leavevmode \\ \textbf{#1}\\ \\}
```

the problem is that sometimes the title is on the bottom of a one page and the text is on the beginning of the second page, or there is a picture between this title and a text. How can I make to have the title and the text without any dividing?

Here is short compilable code example:

```
\documentclass[12pt, twoside]{article}
\usepackage[czech]{babel}
\usepackage{hyperref,xltxtra,graphicx}
\usepackage{float}

\def\podpodsekce#1{\leavevmode \\ \textbf{#1}\\ \\}

\begin{document}
\podpodsekce{Subsubtitle}
Some text that should be after the title.
\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX SX! If  you customise your subsubsection with `titlesec`, it has the `nobottomtitles` option.

Comment: @bernard can you show me how to you it in some small example? I updated the post with the picture of the curret subsubsection title, so I want something that looks similar.

Comment: I can, but please provide a short compilable  code, not just a snippet (from `documentclass` to `\end{document}`)

Comment: @Bernard post updated

Comment: `\subsubsection*{title}` will not show up in the ToC.

Comment: @PeterWilson man you are God, thank you! If i knew this command before I saved many hours!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turning my comment into an answer and extending it:

```
\subsubsection*{title}
```

does not make an entry in the ToC. It is the same with all the starred sectioning commands.

More generally LaTeX associates a level with each division where `\part` has level of -1, `\chapter` has level 0, `\section` level 1, down to `\subparagraph` level 5.

The value of the `secnumdepth` counter controls which divisions will be numbered.

```
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{2}
```

means that `subsections` up to `part` will be numbered; `subsubsections` and below will not be numbered.

The value of the `tocdepth` counter controls what will appear in the ToC.

```
\setcounter{tocdepth}{1}
```

means that only `sections` and above will appear in the ToC.